# AWS SQS + Lambda, get error while executing "DeleteMessage" after doing job on Lambda

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, jobs

I am implementing AWS SQS job queue using `"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.185"`. Jobs are processed correctly (**pull job -> process job -> delete job**) on my VPS using queue command:

`php artisan queue:work`

But with the same **credential**, in Lambda enviroments , Job can't be **deleted** after finished. In shorthand, **pull job -> process job  --X-->  delete job**.
Here are the errors:

> "errorType": "Aws\Sqs\Exception\SqsException",

> "errorMessage": "Error executing "DeleteMessage" on "https://sqs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/SQS-TestJob"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/SQS-TestJob` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:\n<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/">Sender`I (truncated...)\n InvalidClientTokenId (client): The security token included in the request is invalid. - <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/">SenderInvalidClientTokenId`The security token included in the request is invalid.b28151cc-0c42-5eec-be57-08a6207db931"

After visibility time (30 secs in this case), undelete message will come again.
[image: queue]
[image: lambda]

Should I renew token when app bootstrap ?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure about token in PHP SDK, but in general you don't need to explicitly delete messages from queue: "Lambda polls the queue and invokes your Lambda function synchronously with an event that contains queue messages. Lambda reads messages in batches and invokes your function once for each batch. When your function successfully processes a batch, Lambda deletes its messages from the queue."

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha I don't see it deleted in the logs. It is till there and available after visibility time

Comment: It should delete only if function processed the message **successfully**. Try removing part of the function which deletes the messages and see if it works

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha it completed ```function handle()``` without any errors

Comment: Does SQS trigger the lambda or you pull from SQS inside the code?

Comment: Yes, SQS trigger it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If Amazon SQS is triggering the AWS Lambda function**, then the function **should not** retrieve or delete the message in the SQS queue.

Instead, the Lambda function **will be provided the message via the `event` variable**, which replaces the need to retrieve the message from the SQS queue.

When the Lambda function successfully completes without an error, the Lambda service (which runs the function) will automatically delete the message from the SQS queue. If the function does *not* complete successfully, the message will *not* be deleted, which will cause it to reappear on the queue after the Invisibility Period has passed.

So, if SQS is triggering the Lambda function, then the Lambda function does not actually require any permissions to access the Amazon SQS queue.

---

If, instead, the AWS Lambda function is **being triggered in another way** (eg every 5 minutes on a schedule), then the Lambda function would be responsible for calling `ReceiveMessage()` and `DeleteMessage()`.

The function would require an IAM Role that has permission to call both of these functions.

When calling `DeleteMessage()`, the function would pass the `ReceiptHandle` that was provided during the `ReceiveMessage()` call.

Comment: Thanks @John, I understand. Try to try catch ```job->fire()``` , the lambda run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't published the code, I suspect that although you think the same credential is in use, it isn't.  In order to get the lambda to run, you must have assigned a IAM role to it.  When your code attempts to use the underlying AWS routines, it will search automatically first to see if it can find a credential.  The lambda service can automatically provide a temporary access key and secret access key to the running lambda code which can be used to access AWS services that the IAM role assigned to the lambda is permitted to access.  Actually, this is the preferred way in lambda for security reasons so that you don't need hard-coded credentials.

In short, I would validate that the IAM role assigned to the lambda function matches the permissions of the IAM user of your original credential.

Comment: I use only one IAM account

Comment: You may only have one IAM user, but you need to assign an IAM role to lambda to get it to run.  That IAM role will be assigned automatically rotating access keys that you never see.  Ensure the IAM policies assigned to your user are the same as to the lambda role.